# End Users Cannot Access Text Input Box

Tags: javascript, forms, input, z-index

I have an issue with a site I oversee: http://www.aifittings.com that I have not been able to successfully duplicate.  At the top of the page, there is a search box, that contains three text fields.  Now, I have heard from several users that they are not able to click into this box.  I've tested w/ javascript disabled, tested on FF3.0+, Safari 4.0+, Google Chrome 10.0+, and IE6+, checked my z-index values, and no matter what I do, I am unable to duplicate this issue, so therefore, I am unable to find a solution.  I know this cannot be a single instance, since I have heard this complaint from many users.  Does anyone think they might know what is causing this, or a possible solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me in FF, Chrome, IE latests. I've had similar trouble with a div magically covering the textbox in certain browsers. Ofcourse it was due to a mistake i made with positioning a div and after correcting it the problem went away.

Comment: Hmm, actually only tested in IE6 - 8 - 9, and IE8+9 w/ compatibility to replicate IE7, guess it didn't work right.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a little sidenote while looking at your source: On your keyword search form you specify the form method by method-"get" instead of method="get"

Comment: Willempie -- Thanks for noticing that, corrected it.

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy Also [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is a awesome program for testing in different versions of IE.

Comment: Just took a brief look at it, looks like exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix matey:

`.search form{float:left;}`

I think the problem was that your forms were filling the full width of that box, so they were stacking on top of each other. Adding `float` gives them the correct size.

You may want to stick a little `padding-left` in though.

**UPDATE**

You could even do:

`.search form{*float:left;}`

So it only effects IE7 and lower.

Comment: Had to pull a old dell out of retirement for the testing, but you were absolutely right, they were stacking on top of each other, and your solution worked perfectly.  Damn IE Compatibility Mode -- worked fine in IE8 and IE9 in compatibility mode - even though it's supposed to "replicate" IE7.  Thanks again Alex.

Comment: @pennstate_fanboy You're welcome. I wish we had some Men in Black style Neuralizer to erase peoples memory of IE8 and below!